# How to set cache control in aws s3 object while uploading in java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, image-uploading

I tried the following options, but none of them will work

- metadata.setCacheControl("max-age=604800, must-revalidate");
- metadata.addUserMetadata("x-amz-meta-Cache-Control", "max-age=31536000, must-revalidate");
- metadata.setHeader("x-amz-meta-Cache-Control", "max-age=31536000, must-revalidate");
- metadata.addUserMetadata("Cache-Control", "max-age=31536000, must-revalidate");

Kindly help me to resolve this...

Comment: Are you sure it isn't the first one?  That seems correct.

Comment: yes, michael, first one is correct. My Mistake is I passed metadata in PutObjectRequest instead of transferManager.upload(). Now its working fine. Thanks ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First one is the correct approach, what i did wrong is, passed metadata via PutObjectRequest instead of TransferManager upload method. Need to pass metadata in TransferManager upload method.

**metadata.setCacheControl("max-age=604800, must-revalidate");**

Not Correct:

```
ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, PREFIX + folderName + DELIMITER, null, metadata);
```

correct :

```
ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
metadata.setCacheControl("max-age=31536000, must-revalidate");
Upload upload = transferManager.upload(bucketName, PREFIX + folderName + DELIMITER + fileName, fileStream, metadata);
```

Now its working fine.